# how to configure one port to deploy different java web app with "location"?

Tags: spring-boot, nginx-location

I have installed the nginx 1.18.0. Here is part of file `nginx.conf`.

```
    server {
        listen       8082;
        location /lc/ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                      }
        }
```

When I visit http://127.0.0.1:8082/lc ,it gives right outcome,but the web app will response a redirect to /login,so the url changes to http://127.0.0.1:8082/login,the "lc" is missing.It is the same to js/css files.

Comment: Where is "login" coming from?  There has to be some other configuration involved here, or possibly the behavior is being dictated by whatever `http://127.0.0.1:8082/lc` is actually serving up.  Can you show us or describe to us what the server is returning when that link is accessed?  Do you have some sort of authentication enabled in another part of your Nginx configuration?  Does the word "login" appear anywhere in your site's configuration or content?  I'm thinking that it must. - The fact that you're getting the result you expect except for the URL change is particularly interesting.

Comment: If not logging on ,web app will return a redirect to /login.For example,without nginx,if I visit http://127.0.0.1:8080, tht server will response a redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8080/login. In the controller of spring-boot  app, it is just ```return "redirect:/login";```.